# how to make the views well-aligned indpendent of the device

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I've a cutomized **ListView** that consists of **ImageView**, some **TextView** and a Button. when I run the code on code on Huawei the listview and the views inside it are well-aligned, but when I run the same code on samsung galaxy tablet the views gets mixed-up as shown below in the picture

please let me know what should I do to make the views well-aligned indpendent of the device

**code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/vers_img"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ver_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/versicherungsListeActivity_vers_liste_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="ver_name"
            android:textSize="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ver_ges"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/versicherungsListeActivity_vers_liste_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="ver_ges" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/versiecherungsListeActivity_rellay_ver_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/versicherungsListeActivity_vers_liste_padding"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/versicherungsListeActivity_vers_liste_padding"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/versicherungsListeActivity_vers_liste_margin"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/round_corners">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/versicherungsListeActivity_ver_yearly_cost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="409" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/versicherungsListeActivityMain_euro_sign"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/versicherungsListeActivity_ver_yearly_cost"
                android:text="€/Jahr" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/versicherungsListeActivity_ver_in_bearbeitung"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="In Bearbeitung" />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/versButton_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|top"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vers_pers_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:scaleX=".6"
        android:scaleY="0.7" />

</TableRow>


</TableLayout>
```

**image**:

[image]

Comment: post your row.xml layout

Comment: @RjzSatvara ok i posted the code

Comment: don't use exact values for width/height, use wrap_content instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by setting the first linearLayout to have android:layout_height="wrap_content".

actually, the answer of @Senthil Vidhiyakar assisted me to solve this issue, because in his answer he mentioned that the TableRow element
takes its height from the first first child which is in  my case it is the ImageView element.

hence, if the LinearLayout set to have android:layout_height="match_parent", then it will match the height of its parent which is the 
 element which has height as high as the ImageView element. therefore, by setting the LinearLayout set to have android:layout_height="wrap_content", the LinearLayout will expand to contain all the three child views

Answer (score 1):

The table row is not set an explicit height and it takes the height of its first child the imageview with ID vers_img which is 60dp. That makes the next child relativelayout also to take the same overall height which is 60dp...

Note : The px value of dp might change from device to device with resolution of the device.. I prefer using sp instead..

Answer (score 0):

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/versicherungsListeActivity_ver_yearly_cost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="409" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/versicherungsListeActivityMain_euro_sign"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/versicherungsListeActivity_ver_yearly_cost"
                android:text="€/Jahr" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/versicherungsListeActivity_ver_in_bearbeitung"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:text="In Bearbeitung" />
```

replace above code with your layout